# how to generalize a function triggered by scrolling to use in multiple instances?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function that causes the title of a section to become fixed while scrolling through that section and revert to a static element upon reaching the next section.  I'd like to use this effect on multiple sections (.first, .second, .third, ...), however I'm only able to get it to work by having individual functions for each section.

Is there a way to generalize this function so it can work on all of these sections?  I tried using (this) to identify the context but can't get it to work for scrolling.

Here's the function I'm working with:

```
var containerHeight = $('.container').height();

var firstTop = $('.first .label').offset();
var secondTop = $('.second .label').offset();
...

var firstBottom = firstTop.top + (containerHeight - 160);
var secondBottom = secondTop.top + (containerHeight - 160);
...

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > firstTop.top && $(window).scrollTop() < firstBottom){
        $('.first .label').addClass('fixtop').removeClass('fixbottom');
    }
    else if($(window).scrollTop() >= firstBottom) {
        $('.first .label').removeClass('fixtop').addClass('fixbottom');
    }
    else {
        $('.first .label').removeClass('fixtop').removeClass('fixbottom');
    };


    if($(window).scrollTop() > secondTop.top && $(window).scrollTop() < secondBottom){
        $('.second .label').addClass('fixtop').removeClass('fixbottom');
    }
    else if($(window).scrollTop() >= secondBottom) {
        $('.second .label').removeClass('fixtop').addClass('fixbottom');
    }
    else {
        $('.second .label').removeClass('fixtop').removeClass('fixbottom');
    };

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tops = [firstTop, secondTop];
var bottoms = [firstBottom, secondBottom];


$(window).scroll(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < tops.length; i++) {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > tops[i].top && $(window).scrollTop() < bottoms[i]){
            $('.first .label').addClass('fixtop').removeClass('fixbottom');
        }
        else if($(window).scrollTop() >= bottoms[i]) {
            $('.first .label').removeClass('fixtop').addClass('fixbottom');
        }
        else {
            $('.first .label').removeClass('fixtop').removeClass('fixbottom');
        };
    }
})
```

All you have to do is add all you tops to the tops array and same for the bottoms!